# Removing Outermost List

Tags: json, list, dictionary, python-3.5

Assume I have a function that processes an input and returns a JSON data in a list, for example:

```
def findme (name):

    data = ''
    address = 'http://someaddresswithname&format=json'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen (address)
    content = response.read ()

    if content:
        data = json.loads (content.decode ('utf-8'))

    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':

    listfound = []
    names = ['bob', 'alice']

    listfound = map (findme, name)
```

Returned data contains:

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 2'}], [{'A': 5, 'B': 9}]
```

Because I'm using map, it creates another list with the same data.  Listfound is now

```
[[{'A': 1, 'B': 2'}], [{'A': 5, 'B': 9}]]
```

The outer list only has 1 element and it's unncessary to be in a list.  I could iterate over it and create another list but that defeats the efficiency of using "map".  How do I get map to just return the normal list like so?

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 2}, {'A': 5, 'B': 9}]
```

**Updated 1** - Update names to have 2 elements instead of 1 - originally name = ['bob'].  Also fixed the actual list that returns to match additional name elements.

One way that I've tried but it involved nested loops.  Any better alternative?

```
>>> results = [[{'A': 1, 'B': 2}], [{'A': 5, 'B': 9}]]
>>> newresult = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]
>>> newresult
[{'B': 2, 'A': 1}, {'B': 9, 'A': 5}]
```

Comment: `listfound = listfound[0]` or `listfound, = listfound`

Comment: So obvious. I'm over complicating things. Thanks.

Comment: But why are you using map anyway? Just do `listfound = findme('bob')`

Comment: It's because it's a list.  name = ['bob', 'alice', ...]

Comment: But if you are taking only the first thing in the resulting list, that means you are handling only the first item in `name` and can therefore call `findme` directly.

Answer (score 0):

JSON data returns a list and map also puts it in another list, I'll have to massage the data to get my desire output.

Seems like list comprehension is the best way to go.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> def listcomp ():

    sample = [[{'B': 2, 'A': 1}], [{'B': 9, 'A': 5}]]
    results = [item for sublist in sample for item in sublist]

    return results

>>> 

>>> def iterchain ():

    sample = [[{'B': 2, 'A': 1}], [{'B': 9, 'A': 5}]]
    results = list (chain.from_iterable (sample))

    return results

>>> 

>>> timeit.timeit (listcomp, number = 5000000)
7.123541992972605

>>> timeit.timeit (iterchain, number = 5000000)
8.06846271501854
```